Minecraft Pauses When Clicking In-Game
The title says it all. Well, almost all.
I am running BetaCraft (a launcher for old versions of Minecraft) on Ubuntu 22.04, using the recommended Java version (1.8). Everything seems to work okay, until I get to the gameplay. Then, whenever I click a block, either left-click or right-click, the game pauses. I think it is because the game unfocuses when I click.
The computer in question uses Intel i5, and, no graphics card. The game works fine on Windows 10, and Windows 7. I am aware of another question that is almost identical, but it has no answer. How can I fix this issue?
UPDATE
My other Ubuntu computer, which has no touchscreen, but does have an NVIDIA Quadro GPU, also has the same issue listed above. It seems to be related to Ubuntu itself. Still no fixes, though.

Um, are there anything abnormal in the logs, and does your PC have a touchscreen? Also, what is the model of your PC/laptop? A possibility is due to a faulty driver or compatibility, your computer is making you click at 0,0 (bottom left corner) then back at wherever the mouse is.

Also, what's your average framerate and CPU usage? (to rule the other question out)

@aytimothy My PC has a touchscreen. It is an HP Pavilion laptop that is about eight years old. And the framerate is typically above 130 FPS. CPU Usage is about 60%. And that is with other programs running.

Whenever I ran into input issues with older versions of Minecraft on Linux, it almost always came down to the LWJGL libraries that were bundled with them.
I'm not sure how many versions you can jump, but I had a lot of luck with 2.8.0.
From the LWJGL zip file, you can copy the following files:

lwjgl-2.8.0/jar/ into /home/[user]/.minecraft/bin/
lwjgl-2.8.0/natives/ into /home/[user]/.minecraft/bin/natives/

BetaCraft might store its Minecraft files elsewhere, but the relative paths will probably remain the same. If this version of LWJGL doesn't work, you could try newer 2.8 versions... but I'm not sure if anything higher would be compatible.
